# Avoid collisions in case: jquery in javascript to be injected to some web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal:

- There's javascript-file, which contains jquery.
- That javascript-file could be inserted to *any* web service so that possibly two jqueries doesn't collide.

Jquery's noconflict was promising, but it seems that it's not a silver bullet.. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Any hints and suggestions welcome!

Please don't answer "do not put two jqueries there".

Comment: Do you mean that you include the source code of jQuery in that JS file, or only using it? and if yes, how you include it?

Comment: Yes I mean that I include source code of jQuery in that JS file. How would you include it?

Comment: So you have JS file that have **jQuery** source code, and some custom code. and the problem is you'll use that file twice, **OR** you have many files that are structured by the same way?!

Comment: I'll use that JS file only once. The file should be insertable to any web service without collisions.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `JS` file that contains two pieces:

- jQuery core "Injected into this file"
- Custom `JS/jQuery` code.

The problem is you want to use this file anywhere you want and avoid the collisions with the jQuery included in those places.

The solution:

```
<script>
   //  --- This scripts represents your file --- //

   function injectJQuery () {
      // jQuery source code...
   }

   function init() {
      // Check if jQuery is not loaded before
      if(!window.jQuery) {
          injectJQuery();
      }

      // Your custom code...
   }
</script>
```

Now if the webpage is included the jQuery before, you won't load it again, and vise versa.

**Note**: You have to make your file the last loaded script in the page, so that you won't load jQuery, then the page make a request to it again.